# Nested form undefined method `model_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have nested forms dealing with 3 models. Job, Employer, User

The form on the jobs controller needs to create a job, employer and user.

The Job and Employer forms are working correctly, however when I add the User nested form I get the error **"undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class"**

I'm completely confused as to why.

Here is my code:

**Job Model**

```
  attr_accessible :category, :employer_id, :employer_attributes, :user_attributes

  belongs_to :employer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employer, :user
  has_many :applications
  has_many :users, :through => :applications
```

**Employer model**

```
 attr_accessible :companyname, :email, :logo, :password, :url
has_many :jobs
 belongs_to :user
```

**User Model**

```
attr_accessible :admin, :cv, :name, :password, :website, :password_confirmation

  has_many :applications
  has_many :jobs, :through => :applications
  has_one :employer
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>

<%= f.fields_for :employer do |builder| %>
     <%= builder.label :companyname, "Company Name" %>
      <%= builder.text_field :companyname %>
<% end %>

<%= f.fields_for :user do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :email, "Email" %>
     <%= builder.text_field :email %>
 <%= builder.label :password, "Password" %>
        <%= builder.text_field :password %>
<% end %>

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**Job Controller**

```
def new

  @job = Job.new
  @job.employer = @job.build_employer
  @job.user = @job.build_user
```

Answer (score 1):

To doesn't look like your Job model has a user method. You may need to add

```
belongs_to :user
```

Comment: Hi, I've added belongs_to :user to the Jobs model but still getting the undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class error

Comment: do you have the references right in your db? user_id column in jobs table?

Comment: I didn't, but I do now. Getting a "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" on next refresh getting the same undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Take a look at each of the associations to see which is nil. Because it is calling each - this is an association that should be an array.  I don't see it off-hand looking at your code, but you may now be in a good position to debug.

Comment: Sorry for the beginner question, but how do I check each association?

Comment: I just do this in the view <%- raise job.user.inspect %> or <%- raise job.users.inspect %>.  I wonder - is it possible you're looking at job.user vs. job.users?  Also, you look at the form object by doing something like builder.object to see.  And lastly - find the line number of the error.  Again, because it's an array (calling 'each'), it's tough to tell what it could be calling.

Comment: Ok I added the raise to the view but its throwing "undefined local variable or method `job'"  Should I be using job.users??

Comment: Sorry - this comment form wouldn't let me add more than one @ . You can only inspect objects.  In this case @job